# Catch Expression in WordPress Action Hook

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, expression, php-curl

Using WordPress, I am trying to hook an action so when an email is sent, my PHP script is executed and sends a notification through LINE messenger service.

I have built the PHP script, which runs successfully, however I am unable to parse expressions within the email body to add to the notification.

My PHP script which executives on action 'rpress_email_send_after'

```
   <?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: ***
   Plugin URI: ***
   description: >-
   LINE Notification extension
   Version: 1.2
   Author: ***
   Author URI: ***
   License: GPL2
   */

function dcart_line() {
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/multicast');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n    \"to\": 
[\"***LINE ID HERE***\"],\n    \"messages\":[\n        {\n            
\"type\":\"text\",\n            \"text\":\"Order\"$to\n        }\n       \n    ]\n}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer 
 {***BEARER TOKEN****}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
}
add_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', 'dcart_line' );
```

?>

```
Wordpress Template Page I am trying to take parameters from:
$To
$Subject
$Message


// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

/**
 * RPRESS_Emails Class
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 */
class RPRESS_Emails {

    /**
     * Holds the from address
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    private $from_address;

    /**
     * Holds the from name
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    private $from_name;

    /**
     * Holds the email content type
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    private $content_type;

    /**
     * Holds the email headers
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    private $headers;

    /**
     * Whether to send email in HTML
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    private $html = true;

    /**
     * The email template to use
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    private $template;

    /**
     * The header text for the email
     *
     * @since  2.1
     */
    private $heading = '';

    /**
     * Get things going
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function __construct() {

        if ( 'none' === $this->get_template() ) {
            $this->html = false;
        }

        add_action( 'rpress_email_send_before', array( $this, 'send_before' ) );
        add_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', array( $this, 'send_after' ) );

    }

    /**
     * Set a property
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function __set( $key, $value ) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get a property
     *
     * @since 1.0.0.9
     */
    public function __get( $key ) {
        return $this->$key;
    }

    /**
     * Get the email from name
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function get_from_name() {
        if ( ! $this->from_name ) {
            $this->from_name = rpress_get_option( 'from_name', get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_from_name', wp_specialchars_decode( $this- 
>from_name ), $this );
    }

    /**
     * Get the email from address
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function get_from_address() {
        if ( ! $this->from_address ) {
            $this->from_address = rpress_get_option( 'from_email' );
        }

        if( empty( $this->from_address ) || ! is_email( $this->from_address ) ) {
            $this->from_address = get_option( 'admin_email' );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_from_address', $this->from_address, $this );
    }

    /**
     * Get the email content type
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function get_content_type() {
        if ( ! $this->content_type && $this->html ) {
            $this->content_type = apply_filters( 'rpress_email_default_content_type', 
 'text/html', $this );
        } else if ( ! $this->html ) {
            $this->content_type = 'text/plain';
        }

        return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_content_type', $this->content_type, $this );
    }

    /**
     * Get the email headers
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function get_headers() {
        if ( ! $this->headers ) {
            $this->headers  = "From: {$this->get_from_name()} <{$this- 
   >get_from_address()}>\r\n";
            $this->headers .= "Reply-To: {$this->get_from_address()}\r\n";
            $this->headers .= "Content-Type: {$this->get_content_type()}; charset=utf- 
  8\r\n";
        }

        return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_headers', $this->headers, $this );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve email templates
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function get_templates() {
        $templates = array(
            'default' => __( 'Default Template', 'restropress' ),
            'none'    => __( 'No template, plain text only', 'restropress' )
        );

        return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_templates', $templates );
    }

    /**
     * Get the enabled email template
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function get_template() {
        if ( ! $this->template ) {
            $this->template = rpress_get_option( 'email_template', 'default' );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_template', $this->template );
    }

    /**
     * Get the header text for the email
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function get_heading() {
        return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_heading', $this->heading );
    }

    /**
     * Parse email template tags
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @param string $content
     */
    public function parse_tags( $content ) {

        // The email tags are parsed during setup for purchase receipts and sale 
   notifications
        // Onoce tags are not restricted to payments, we'll expand this. 

        return $content;
    }

    /**
     * Build the final email
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @param string $message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function build_email( $message ) {

        if ( false === $this->html ) {
            return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_message', wp_strip_all_tags( $message ), 
  $this );
        }

        $message = $this->text_to_html( $message );

        ob_start();

        rpress_get_template_part( 'emails/header', $this->get_template(), true );

        /**
         * Hooks into the email header
         *
         * @since  1.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'rpress_email_header', $this );

        if ( has_action( 'rpress_email_template_' . $this->get_template() ) ) {
            /**
             * Hooks into the template of the email
             *
             * @param string $this->template Gets the enabled email template
             * @since  1.0.0
             */
            do_action( 'rpress_email_template_' . $this->get_template() );
        } else {
            rpress_get_template_part( 'emails/body', $this->get_template(), true );
        }

        /**
         * Hooks into the body of the email
         *
         * @since  1.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'rpress_email_body', $this );

        rpress_get_template_part( 'emails/footer', $this->get_template(), true );

        /**
         * Hooks into the footer of the email
         *
         * @since  1.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'rpress_email_footer', $this );

        $body    = ob_get_clean();
        $message = str_replace( '{email}', $message, $body );

        return apply_filters( 'rpress_email_message', $message, $this );
    }

    /**
     * Send the email
     * @param  string  $to               The To address to send to.
     * @param  string  $subject          The subject line of the email to send.
     * @param  string  $message          The body of the email to send.
     * @param  string|array $attachments Attachments to the email in a format supported by 
  wp_mail()
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function send( $to, $subject, $message, $attachments = '' ) {

        if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) && ! did_action( 'admin_init' ) ) {
            _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'You cannot send email with RPRESS_Emails 
   until init/admin_init has been reached', 'restropress' ), null );
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Hooks before the email is sent
         *
         * @since  1.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'rpress_email_send_before', $this );

        $subject = $this->parse_tags( $subject );
        $message = $this->parse_tags( $message );

        $message = $this->build_email( $message );

        $attachments = apply_filters( 'rpress_email_attachments', $attachments, $this );

        $sent       = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $this->get_headers(), $attachments 
);
        $log_errors = apply_filters( 'rpress_log_email_errors', true, $to, $subject, 
$message );

        if( ! $sent && true === $log_errors ) {
            if ( is_array( $to ) ) {
                $to = implode( ',', $to );
            }

            $log_message = sprintf(
                __( "Email from RestroPress failed to send.\nSend time: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: 
  %s\n\n", 'restropress' ),
                date_i18n( 'F j Y H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
                $to,
                $subject
            );

            error_log( $log_message );
        }

        /**
         * Hooks after the email is sent
         *
         * @since  1.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', $this );

        return $sent;

    }

    /**
     * Add filters / actions before the email is sent
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function send_before() {
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', array( $this, 'get_from_address' ) );
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', array( $this, 'get_from_name' ) );
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', array( $this, 'get_content_type' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Remove filters / actions after the email is sent
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function send_after() {
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from', array( $this, 'get_from_address' ) );
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', array( $this, 'get_from_name' ) );
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', array( $this, 'get_content_type' ) );

        // Reset heading to an empty string
        $this->heading = '';
    }

    /**
     * Converts text to formatted HTML. This is primarily for turning line breaks into <p> 
 and <br/> tags.
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    public function text_to_html( $message ) {

        if ( 'text/html' == $this->content_type || true === $this->html ) {
            $message = apply_filters( 'rpress_email_template_wpautop', true ) ? wpautop( 
  $message ) : $message;
            $message = apply_filters( 'rpress_email_template_make_clickable', true ) ? 
   make_clickable( $message ) : $message;
            $message = str_replace( '&#038;', '&amp;', $message );
        }

        return $message;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dcart_line() {

add_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', 'dcart_line' );

do_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', $this );
```

You are sending $this to the action, but you don't accept it as a parameter in the function hooked to the action.

If you want to get $this in the function, then have a parameter for it to be in the function definition:

```
function dcart_line( $var ) {

add_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', 'dcart_line', 10, 1 );

do_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', $this );
```

Then, in your function, $var will be $this.

Also, you appear to be using $to, but not sending it to the action to be passed to the function. So, maybe you need to send that separately.

```
function dcart_line( $var, $to ) {

add_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', 'dcart_line', 10, 2 );

do_action( 'rpress_email_send_after', $this, $to );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when I revise the code using your edit, it does not work for me. Can you add any more detail to help me clarify @otto